# I was writting java prorgram with regex and I want to read and write from file

Tags: java, regex, file-io

assume that input file ( book.txt) contain sentences for example:

```
book 'learning java' for doctor  ahmed mohamed.
the best title is:How to program for simth sahg.
```

i want to read each sentence from file( book.txt)  instead of enter from keyboard and match each sentence in file with 3 patterns:

```
 String p1 = "(book|\\)|\\:) (.*) for( doctor| author|) (.*)";
String p2 = "regex two";
String p3 = "regex three";

// matcher for each of the patterns .
Matcher m1=Pattern.compile(p1).matcher(inputtext);
Matcher m2=Pattern.compile(p2).matcher(inputtext);
Matcher p3=Pattern.compile(p3).matcher(inputtext);
```

if sentence match any pattern then will extract and write[ Author , title] in new file (bookout.txt)

or not match any pattern write "the sentence "not match in (bookout.txt)

the cod is

```
    String p1 = "(book|\\)|\\:) (.*) for( doctor| author|) (.*)";
    String p2 = "regex two";
    String p3 = "regex three";
String inputtext = null;
            // matcher for each of the patterns .
            Matcher m1=Pattern.compile(p1).matcher(inputtext);
            Matcher m2=Pattern.compile(p2).matcher(inputtext);
            Matcher m3=Pattern.compile(p3).matcher(inputtext);


            try {
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("bookout.txt",true));

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("book.txt") ));
                        inputtext= br.readLine();
                    while ((inputtext=br.readLine())!= null)
                            System.out.println(inputtext);

            String author=null;
        String title = null;

        if (m1.find()) {                //if input matches p1
            title = m1.group(2).trim();
            author = m1.group(4).trim();
        } else if (m2.find()) {           //else if input matches p2
            title = m2.group(1).trim();
            author = m2.group(3).trim();
        } else if (m3.find()) {            //else if input matches p3
            author = m3.group(2).trim();
            title = m3.group(4).trim();
        }

        if (author ==null || title == null) {   //If no matches set the author and title strings...
            bw.write("inputNot match");    //There's no match
        } else {                                //Otherwise...

            bw.write("Author : " + author);
            bw.write("Title : " + title);
            bw.close();

        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
```

please help me,how to display output instead of  display on console will write in another file (bookout.txt)

Comment: Please, try a quick search before posting: https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=java%20write%20to%20file

Comment: Why are you doing this: `BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("bookout.txt",true));
                bw.write(inputtext);
                bw.close();` when inputtext is null? This is what you have to do instead of System.out.println().

Answer (score 0):

Use your `BufferedWriter` to write output to the file. For example:

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("bookout.txt",true));

// write to the file
bw.write("Author : " + author);

// close the writer when you have finished writing everything
bw.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
System.out.println("Author : " + author);
    System.out.println("Title : " + title);
```

Use

```
bw.write(inputtext )
```